# How to add in gnuplot a vertical line on a 3D splot?

Tags: plot, gnuplot, data-visualization, line, heatmap

I have a 3D plot with the option:
`set view map`
And I would like to add a vertical line from (30,0) to (30,20), I tried:

```
set arrow from 30,0 to 30,20 nohead lc rgb 'red'
splot 'data.csv' using 1:2:3 with pm3d
```

But I don't see any line, what am I doing wrong ?
This is the image on which I would like to add the vertical line
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "trick" is `front`. Check `help layers`.

**Code:**

```
### arrow on top of map view
reset session

set view map
set arrow 1 from 50,0 to 50,20 nohead lc rgb 'red' front

set xrange[0:140]
set yrange[0:20]

splot x*y/3000 w pm3d notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]